# The first observation has no line number

Tags: r

I am reading in a data set looking like this:

[image]

And my code was as below:

```
NatPark <- read.delim (paste0(dirdata,"NatPark_Plus.dat"),
                  header= TRUE, 
                  sep = "\t",
                  quote = "\"",
                  dec = ".",
                  fill = TRUE,
                  as.is = c("ParkName", "State"))
```

And then I've got the warning as below:

> Warning messages:
>   1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
>     incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on '/Volumes/Elements/STAT_611/611/DATA/DATA11/NatPark_Plus.dat'
>   2: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
>     not all columns named in 'as.is' exist

So I changed the "header=TRUE" to "header=FALSE",
as below:

```
   NatPark <- read.delim (paste0(dirdata,"NatPark_Plus.dat"),
                    header= FALSE, 
                      sep = "\t",
                      quote = "\"",
                      dec = ".",
                      fill = TRUE,
                      as.is = c("ParkName", "State"))
```

I've got the same warning message:

> Warning messages:
>   1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
>     incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on '/Volumes/Elements/STAT_611/611/DATA/DATA11/NatPark_Plus.dat'
>   2: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
>     not all columns named in 'as.is' exist

The line numbers all showed up this time, as below.
However, I do not understand what it meant by str(NatPark).
What was that "v1"? And "4 1 5 2 3" following?
Thank you for any suggestions!
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I don't think the "as.is" columns ParkName and State are variable names in the dataset. Those would normally be in the first line/header that says "ParkName \t State \t Year \t Number)".

Comment: This isn't a delimited file, it's a fixed width file. You need to use `read.fwf()` not `read.delim()`, specifying the column widths in characters.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked much with `.dat` files, but if you could share a download link I could help troubleshoot further. So far I can provide these insights:

- `V1` (and V2, V3, V4...) refers to the column name that R automatically assigns when there are no headers. Since there is only V1, then of course R thinks you only have 1 column with the current settings.
- Regarding `"4 1 5 2 3"` that you see from the output of `str` that refers to the numeric levels since this factor variable (in this case the entire line is read as one variable).  By default, R always sorts levels in alphabetical order. This example from the iris dataset should help clarify:

```r
str(iris)
#> 'data.frame':    150 obs. of  5 variables:
#>  $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
#>  $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
#>  $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
#>  $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
#>  $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
head(iris$Species)
#> [1] setosa setosa setosa setosa setosa setosa
#> Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
levels(iris$Species)
#> [1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"
```

Created on 2018-08-18 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

You can see that the value `setosa` is considered `1` since its the first level, `setosa` is 2, and `virginica` is 3. However, this should all be a moot point since you don't want to read the entire line as one variable.

Comment: Thank you! The link is as below: https://rit0-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/jc3992_rit_edu/Etz3CcF9wztOlS5G43Hs7SwBs61SYlOyJP-Bu0axrUWH-Q?e=nMWCE3

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your main problem, I was able to put together a custom function to parse the data for your data only. In the future, if there is an option to quote text in the source data things could be a lot simpler. Anyways, hope this works for you! You just need to set the column names and change some of the columns to numeric from character.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

directory <- "/Users/jas/Desktop"
filename <- "NatPark_Plus.dat"
file <- file.path(directory, filename)

# tabs
data <- read.delim(file, header = FALSE, sep = "\t")
#> Warning in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote =
#> quote, : incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on '/Users/jas/
#> Desktop/NatPark_Plus.dat'

# We have 5 records, but the spacing amongst them is uneven and some words with spaces

text <- data$V1

# Parse text to make same number of columns - 4
# Creates a separate dataframe for each row
parse_text_to_df <- function(x) {
  # Find more than one spaces and replace with tab
  x <- gsub("[ ]{2,}", "\t", x)
  # replace remaining space with tab (cannot use comma since numbers have comma)
  x <- gsub(" ", "\t", x)
  # Should be only 3 tabs on each line - WORKS FOR THIS DATASET ONLY
  total_tabs <- stringr::str_count(x, "\t")
  # If we have those words with spaces, we need to remove the extra tabs between them
  if (total_tabs[1] > 3) {
    num_tabs_to_remove <- total_tabs - 3
    for (i in range(num_tabs_to_remove)) {
      x <- sub("\t", " ", x)
    }
  }
  # Convert to an object that can be read back into a dataframe
  x <- readLines(textConnection(x))
  df <- read.delim(text = x, header = FALSE, sep = "\t") %>%
    mutate_all(as.character)
  return(df)
}

# Combine each of the 1 row dataframes into one dataframe (all character vectors)
df <- text %>% map_df(parse_text_to_df)
df
#>                      V1       V2   V3        V4
#> 1           Yellowstone ID/MT/WY 1872 4,065,493
#> 2            Everglades       FL 1934 1,398,800
#> 3              Yosemite       CA 1864   760,917
#> 4 Great Smoky Mountains    NC/TN 1926   520,269
#> 5        Wolf Trap Farm       VA 1966       130
```

Created on 2018-08-18 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).